# Dynamic event names for NestJS websocket

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

In NestJS, in order to subscribe to events in socket.io communication we can use @SubscribeMessage annotation, but, in this way we can only have "hardcoded" event names.

Is there a posibility to dynamically listen for events ?
For example, to listen to events with format prefix.. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no answer, I thought I'd try one. Sorry for the lack of details.

I have not found an "elegant" way to do it with the @SubscribeMessage, but you can directly add a listener to any connected sockets.

This will let you format whatever event name you want. You can also save the listener, which will let you unsubscribe from it!

```js
clientSocket.on(prefix + suffix, (...args: any) => {

  functionToCall(clientSocket);
  clientSocket.emit(prefix + suffix + 'Response', "your response");
});
```

Your frontend can do the same thing with the server socket.